# Change YYYYMMDDHHMMSS of INT type to YYYY-MM-DD of VARCHAR in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, time, datetime-format

In my table of MySQL server, there is a column storing time information in YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format in INT type. An example will be 20200715130000. When I query these data, I would like to turn them into YYYY-MM-DD format in VARCHAR type. For example: "2020-07-15". Currently my approach is doing

```
(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(my_time as VARCHAR), 1, 4),
'-', SUBSTRING(CAST(my_time as VARCHAR), 5, 2),
'-', SUBSTRING(CAST(my_time as VARCHAR), 7, 2)))
```

say if the columns are called `my_time`. But I am not sure if this is the effective and elegant way of reformatting these data. Could anybody have a look? Thanks in advance.

Change YYYYMMDDHHMMSS of INT type to YYYY-MM-DD of VARCHAR in SQL

Comment: You should use neither, `varchar` nor `integer` for storing date/times. Use one of the [date/time types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could just convert to a date:

```
select date(left(my_time, 8))
```

or:

```
select date(my_time / 1000000)
```

Comment: what is the reason for the left ``..left(my_time...)``

Comment: @linkonabe . . . I guess it is not really needed.  However, I'm uncomfortable because the question called 20200715130000 an `INT`, but 20,200,715,130,000 is too big to fit into a regular sized integer.